# I need to validate that a submitted MIME type does not have a newline character using regex

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

I have tried:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\n", ErrorMessage = "Error")] // Needs to not allow newline characters
public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
```

but it always fails when I attempt to upload a legitimate `.bmp` file.

I am not sure how to format this line appropriately to prevent newline characters.

Also - are there any other considerations I should take when validating a MIME type?

**Solved**

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\n]+", ErrorMessage = "Error")]
```

Comment: Its `\n` for newline and not `/n` right?

Comment: Made the change, but validation still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just specifying `\n` as the regex. Your legitimate files will not be matching `\n` and hence they are treated as `NO_MATCH`. You want it the other way. ie the filename mustn't contain `\n`. Try

```
[^\n]+
```

This says, ***match a string of 1-any number of characters ( you can specify string range using {m,n} syntax if you wish to) not containing a newline character***.